# Subjunctive I VS Subjunctive II in reported speech (aus der Nähe betrachtet)

Tags: subjunctive, participle, indirect-speech

> Gauß kam auf den Zufall zu sprechen, den Feind allen Wissens, den er
>   immer habe besiegen wollen. Aus der Nähe **betrachtet**, sehe man hinter
>   jedem Ereignis die unendliche Feinheit des Kausalgewebes. Trete man
>   weit genug zurück, **offenbarten** sich die großen Muster.

Above is a quote from *die Vermessung der Welt*, and according to the rule of reported speech:

> If the forms of the indicative and the subjunctive I are identical,
>   the subjunctive II or the forms with würde are preferred. ([link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Indirekte.html?MenuId=Word212310))

The usage of *offenbarten* instead of *offenbaren* fits this rule. However, the word *betrachtet* is also identical as its indicative form. Why doesn't the author use *betrachtetet* instead?

Comment: The comma after “betrachtet” seems wrong to me. Is it really in your source text?

Comment: @CarstenS yes, that comma is correct, I believe it means "viewed from up close, one could detect the infinite fineness of the web of causality behind every event."

Comment: I understand the meaning, and I still think that the comma is wrong. That there is a comma in the English translation is not relevant. But I see that it is in the original.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the quote, "aus der Nähe betrachtet" is a [participle clause](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Partizip.html?lang=en). I.e. *betrachtet* isn't the indicative of *betrachten*, but the perfect participle. The clause is used as an adverb to *sehen* in the clause that follows. It remains unchanged in reported speech.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Otherwise I wouldn't realize that I looked at the totally wrong direction.